Writing an NC-file in int-16 data type in r
I have a numeric array of dimensions 1386, 585, 1800 (Lon,Lat,time) and want to store this array in a nc-file format.
Since the data spans 150 years and has a 4-km resolution it turned out to be huge NC file (5.48 GB).
So we tried to save the data as integers as a way to compress the size of the nc files. The idea behind this is, that we don't need the full precision of a float to represent the value. For example, we probably only need max. 2 digits of precision (to the hundredth place) for any SPEI value. So we create a new variable:
x  = int16((spei - add_offset)/scale_factor)

with
scale_factor: 0.01
add_offset: -5.0

When someone wants to recreate the SPEI, they can use
spei = scale_factor * x + add_offset

to see that the values of SPEI with 2 digits of precision.
Here's the code that I tried.
        library(ncdf4)
        
        # Load the Array file
        load("dataarray.RData")
        
        # Open the NetCDF template file to get lat and lon values
        file_nc_maxT1 <- nc_open("macav2metdata_PotEvap_bcc-csm1-1_r1i1p1_rcp45_2096_2099_CONUS_monthly.nc")
        nclat <- as.numeric(ncvar_get(file_nc_maxT1,"lat"))
        nclon <- as.numeric(ncvar_get(file_nc_maxT1,"lon"))
        nc_close(file_nc_maxT1)
        
        # Define the filename for the new NetCDF file
        filename <- "macav2metdata_1-month_SPEI_bcc-csm1-1_r1i1p1_rcp45_1950_2099_CONUS_monthly-integer.nc"
        
        # Create the NetCDF file
        nx <- length(nclon)
        ny <- length(nclat)
        lon <- ncdim_def("lon", units = "degrees_east", longname = "longitude", vals = nclon)
        lat <- ncdim_def("lat", units = "degrees_north", longname = "latitude", vals = nclat)
        nctime <- seq(as.Date("1950-01-01"),as.Date("2099-12-31"),by="months")
        time <- ncdim_def("time", units = "days since 1900-01-01 00:00:00", vals = as.numeric(nctime - as.Date("1900-01-01")))
        mv <- -999
        #var <- ncvar_def("SPEI", "1-month SPEI", list(lon, lat, time), longname="1-month Standardized Precipitation Evapotranspiration Index (SPEI)", mv)
        var2 <- ncvar_def("SPEI", "1-month SPEI", list(lon, lat, time), longname="1-month Standardized Precipitation Evapotranspiration Index (SPEI)", mv, prec="integer")
        
        ncnew <- nc_create(filename, list(var2))
                
        # Define scale factor and add offset
        scale_factor <- 0.01
        add_offset <- -5.0
        
        # This step takes a lot of computation effort since it is cell wise might decrease the storage
        dataarray2 <- apply(dataarray, c(1, 2, 3), function(x) as.integer((x - add_offset) / scale_factor))

        # The dataarray still remains in float format however computationally fast 
    
    dataarray2 <- (dataarray- add_offset)/scale_factor
            
        # Write data array to the NetCDF file
        ncvar_put(ncnew, var2, dataarray2)
        
        # Close the NetCDF file
        nc_close(ncnew)
        print("NC File Created")

Even when I specify data type as integer in the var definition, the output size trunes out to be the same. I want this data to be stored as int16 datatype.

Why do you create dataarray2 twice?

Thanks for pointing that out! As I mentioned I am not using the apply function since it takes lot of computational effort. Hence, I am commenting that line when I run the code. However, the one below it is actually the one I am using.

This:
dataarray2 <- apply(dataarray, c(1, 2, 3), function(x) as.integer((x - add_offset) / scale_factor))

is not the way you should do it. R is optimised for vectorized computation (as is your CPU, incidentally) and you break that by computing the value per pixel. Instead, you should simply do:
dataarray2 <- as.integer((dataarray - add_offset) / scale_factor)

Lightning fast, no matter how big your data.
Then when you create your new NetCDF file, you should add attributes add_offset and scale_factor to the variable so that the "unpacking" of the data by the user is automatically handled. You can do this with ncatt_put().
